# System.out.printf() usage

Tags: java, string, formatting

I am new to Java. While learning the `printf` method I came across the below question:

What would be the output of following program?

```
System.out.printf("%1$d + %b", 456, false);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("%1$d + %b", 456);
```

The answer is:

```
456 + true
456 + true
```

Can someone help me to understand how true is getting printed without me passing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`1$` is called *Explicit indexing*, the successive format of `%1$d` will not lead to the increment of index, so it will also use`456` to format `%b`, and according to the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

> If the argument arg is null, then the result is "false". If arg is a
>   boolean or Boolean, then the result is the string returned by
>   String.valueOf(arg). Otherwise, the result is "true".

that's why you always get `true`.

To get false:

```
System.out.printf("%1$d + %b", null); // null + false
```

or remove explicit indexing:

```
System.out.printf("%d + %b", 456, null); // 456 + false
```

Check the doc of [`java.uti.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more.

Comment: You should also explain that for format specifiers with no explicit (`#$`) or relative (`<`) index like `%b`, the index normally starts at 1 and increases with each successive format specifier, but when you mix format specifiers with indexes and ones without, the ones without *do not* advance because of the ones that specify an index. Thus, `%b` is still pointing at the *first* argument.